# Removing objects with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm getting to know the lambda syntax and have come to something that tickles my mind:

```
private ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void remove(Person person){
    this.list.remove(person);
}

public void run(){

    list.stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() > 15).forEach(p -> p.setAge(p.getAge() + 1));

    list.stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() > 15).forEach(PersonDatabase::remove);; //Syntax error

}
```

When I try to remove objects using the last line of code, I get an error saying the method is not static. Why can't I refer to the class I'm already in, but when I use `Person::getName` which also is not static, it works fine?

Comment: What's wrong with `list.removeIf(p -> p.getAge() > 15);` ?

Comment: @AlexisC, that will not cause `PersonDatabase.remove` to be called.

Comment: @aioobe I know it's not the main point of the question, but `PersonDatabase.remove` is only calling `remove` on the list. I just wanted to point out that as it stands this method is useless and you could directly filter the list.

Comment: Supposedly the code is simplified for the sake of the question (why else would you first set the age of all persons above 15 years, and then remove them? Even if `removeIf` could be used instead, that's not what the question is about at all. The question why static and non-static methods work the way they do.

Comment: And that's why I posted a comment instead of an answer....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't I refer to the class I'm already in?

If `remove` is non-static it needs a receiver (an object to call the method on).

If this code is inside `PersonDatabase`, you should use this syntax: `this::remove`.

> but when I use `Person::getName` which also is not static, it works fine?

This is because `p -> p.getName()` is (pretty much) equivalent to `Person::getName`. The argument `p` is automatically chosen as receiver for the call to `Person::getName`.

In other words, both this variant

```
/* Static Person method */ static void method(Person p) { ... }
```

and this variant

```
/* Non-static Person method */ void method() { ... }
```

can be used as `Person::method` when iterating over `Person` objects. In the former case, `p` will be passed as argument, in the latter case `p` will be used as receiver.

Answer (score 0):

`PersonDatabase::remove` has two arguments - one implicit - the current `PersonDatabase` instance, and the other explicit - the passed `Person` instance.

Therefore you can't use this method reference where only a single `Person` instance is available. When you change your remove method to be static, you eliminate the implicit `PersonDatabase` argument, leaving you with a single `Person` argument, which causes your method to match the parameter expected by `forEach`.